# Jquery .append ( ) and manipulating inside contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Just like on facebook, I want to make a sidebar that has the names of friends in which the user can click to open up a corresponding message_block that contains a message_tab to open a flyout with the previous messages and form for new ones.

**HTML**

```
<div class = "dock">
    <div class = "docking_tabs">

    </div>
</div>
```

I have a problem with .append( ) and being able to manipulate the contents inside. This code works fine on the first try. However when I make a new message tab the previously made tab does not respond. Here is what I have:

**JavaScript**

```
$('.chat_list').click(function(){

    var user_id = $(this).attr('value');
    var el = $('<div class = "message_block">'+
        '<div class = "message_tab">'+ '</div>' +

        '<div class = "message_flyout">' +
        '<div class = "message_content">' +
        '<div class = "message_header">'+ '</div>' +
        '<div class = "conversation_scroll">' +
        '<div class = "scroll_content">' + '</div>' + '</div>' +
        '<div class = "message_form">' +
        "<form method= 'POST' action= 'http://localhost:8000/newtch' accept-charset= 'UTF-8'>" + "<input name='_token' type='hidden' value='2rS54FJZJZhWPplLmBJSH4CsID7Pgec7iPsDtrnm'>" +
        '<div class = "message_form">' +
        "<input class='input-mini' placeholder='Type a message' name='status' type='text'>" +
        '</div>'+
        "</form>" +
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>');

    $('.docking_tabs').append(el);

    $('.message_tab').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass(user_id);
        $(this).siblings('.message_flyout').toggle();
    });

    $('.message_header').on('click', function(){
        console.log('clicked');
        $(this).closest('.message_flyout').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code work fine i can't see where is the problem, what you mean by _the previously made tab does not respond_??

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki when i make two message tabs the previous tab will not open(toggle) the corresponding message_flyout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$('.message_tab').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass(user_id);
    $(this).siblings('.message_flyout').toggle();
});
```

You're not just adding a click handler to the element you just created, you're *also* adding *another* click handler to all previously created elements.  Which means the "previous tab" now has two click handlers both executing this:

```
$(this).siblings('.message_flyout').toggle();
```

Which would essentially cancel one another out.

Instead of adding a new handler every time you create an element, [use event delegation](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/on-on-or-event-delegation-explained.html) to have a single handler for the whole page:

```
$(document).on('click', '.message_tab', function(){
    $(this).addClass(user_id);
    $(this).siblings('.message_flyout').toggle();
});
```

Execute this once when the page loads (instead of in the `'.chat_list'` click handler).  That way there's just one top-level handler for all matching `'.message_tab'` elements.

So you end up with something more like this:

```
$('.chat_list').click(function(){
    var user_id = $(this).attr('value');
    var el = $('<div class = "message_block">'+
        '<div class = "message_tab">'+ '</div>' +

    '<div class = "message_flyout">' +
        '<div class = "message_content">' +
            '<div class = "message_header">'+ '</div>' +
                '<div class = "conversation_scroll">' +
                    '<div class = "scroll_content">' + '</div>' +      '</div>' +
                        '<div class = "message_form">' +
                        "<form method= 'POST' action= 'http://localhost:8000/newtch' accept-charset= 'UTF-8'>" + "<input name='_token' type='hidden' value='2rS54FJZJZhWPplLmBJSH4CsID7Pgec7iPsDtrnm'>" +
                            '<div class = "message_form">' +
                                 "<input class='input-mini' placeholder='Type a message' name='status' type='text'>" +
                            '</div>'+
                         "</form>" +
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
    '</div>');

    $('.docking_tabs').append(el);
});

$(document).on('click', '.message_tab', function(){
    $(this).addClass(user_id);
    $(this).siblings('.message_flyout').toggle();
});

$(document).on('click', '.message_header', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    $(this).closest('.message_flyout').toggle();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I did some approach here:

Try to replace:

```
$('.message_tab').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass(user_id);
    $(this).siblings('.message_flyout').toggle();
});

$('.message_header').on('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    $(this).closest('.message_flyout').toggle();
})
```

with this:

```
el.find('.message_tab').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass(user_id);
    $(this).siblings('.message_flyout').toggle();
});

el.find('.message_header').on('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    $(this).closest('.message_flyout').toggle();
});
```

Here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/L3xbyeff/1/. Let me know if this is what you need :)

Good luck!